# Drawing a line between two points avoiding the obstacles

Tags: matlab

I have a problem in MATLAB, that I want to draw a line between two points like start (50,50) and end point (500,200) where (50,50) and (500,200) represents the (x,y) coordinates of these points. To draw this line I have to check whether there is any object/obstacle base on a condition that radius of this obstacle is less or equal to a specific value then it should go around the object following the shape of the obstacle,In this case obstacles are round, they can be squared shape like buildings or rectangular shape. so that I can reach from start to end point passing through these obstructions/obstacles.

I am not getting how to go through, As i have tried straight lines with the help of plot but no good results.

If you can give hint to sort out this issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If there is an obstacle with a large radius, then what would you like to do, ideally?

Comment: Sounds like [Path Finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding)

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar.. Well according to Rollen D'Souza reply. its seems like path tracking .

Well if the obstacle with large radius come in my way i will move along the obstacle surface and try to reach the end point avoiding the obstacles in my way.

Actually i am not able to put picture, otherwise I show you that I have done but this line is going through obstacles, I want that it follow the surface of obstacle and try to reach the end point.

Comment: @RollenD'Souza....You got the problem exactly..but I cant put image otherwise you people get the clear image of what i wish to do and where I am stuck.

Comment: If the proposed duplicate doesn't fully answer your question, you can edit your post to describe where you are stuck and add a link to your image. A user with higher rep can then add the image for you.